# Send data to a pc localhost with ESP-01 wifi module

Tags: esp8266, wifi

i use a linux machine with a localhost php server installed. Wifi machine is connected to the ESP-01 module (access point mode) and i can send several datas to the Arduino via the ESP-01 set as:

```
  sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
  sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
  sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
  sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80
```

The php server can send data by GET method and Arduino receives pin=11:

```
 http://192.168.4.1:80/?pin=11
```

But, now, i would like to send to the php server datas from the Arduino. I tried this configuration but in my sketch but, it returns, error.

```
sendData("AT+CIPSTART=0,'TCP','http://localhost',80\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
```

Serial monitor:

```
   ERROR
   AT+CIPSTART=0,'TCP','http://localhost/test_php',80

   Link type ERROR
```

So please, how can i send and receive data with my ESP-01 module?

Answer (score 2):

"localhost" is a name associated with the loopback interface of your computer. That is, 127.0.0.1.

It is *not* the address of your computer on the network. The only computer that can talk to "localhost" is the computer itself.

Instead of "localhost" you *must* use the IP address of your computer (or a FQDN that resolves to the IP address of your computer).

And you cannot open a TCP connection to a URL.  You open a TCP connection to an IP or FQDN.

You really should learn the basics of IP networks before trying to write software for them.

---

Since your PC can communicate with the ESP8266 on 192.168.4.1 I assume that you are running the ESP8266 in SOFTAP mode and you have a WiFi interface connected to that access point. If so that WiFi interface will have a 192.168.4.x address assigned to it.  That is the address you must open with a TCP connection on port 80 to connect to your apache server.

For example:

```
sendData("AT+CIPSTART=0,'TCP','192.168.4.3',80\r\n",1000,DEBUG);
```

Then you can craft a suitable HTTP request to send the data.

Comment: i replaced localhot by 127.0.0.1. Terminal returns same error Link type

Comment: I said *not* localhost.

Comment: And you deleted the protocol.

Comment: ERROR
AT+CIPSTART=0,'TCP','127.0.0.1/test_php',80
Link type ERROR

Comment: Do you read? I said do NOT use the localhost address. Use the IP address of your computer on the network. And put back in the protocol that you deleted.

Comment: Although you are using raw TCP commands to try and acess a URL. YOu want *only* an IP address in there. And *not* 127.0.0.1

Comment: Learn the basics of networking before you try working with networks.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm a beginner with arduino and i try to understand how it works with ESP-01 and distant php server. The ESP is not linked to my house network and i don't want it as. i need more help...

Comment: If your PC can communicate with the ESP8266 then there must be some form of network between them.

Comment: Yes, pc can send, but how can arduino do the same to the pc?

Comment: By opening a connection to the IP address of your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt and type `ipconfig`
Under `IPv4 Address` you can see IP or your PC.
That IP address is address of localhost(because your PC is a "server" within your local/home network).

Don't forget to config XAMP/WAMP to listen special addresses. And of course if you want use localhost, your PC must be on.

> Yes, pc can send, but how can arduino do the same to the pc

Yes, it can. PC(localhost) is server and Arduino is client, like Stackexchange is host and your PC is a client (to Stackexchange). I hope you get it

```
 The ESP is not linked to my house network and i don't want it as
```

You can use public server, but you need to Know IP address of the server.

Comment: he connects to esp8266 as AP. so not the address on home network, but the address on WiFi interface connected to esp8266